# how to read data from apiResponse in Nodejs typescript?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-api-nodejs-client

I want to read data from a googleapis call. I am using async-await. But I am not sure how to read the data that I am getting back.

```
async function makeCall(params:String){
  const apiResponse = await goopleapi.particular.get(params);
  console.log(`not really sure how to read -- ${apiResponse}`;
  // problem is the log prints [object Object].
}
```

How do I get the log from printing `[object Object]` to the actual content of the response? Ultimately I want to read the json that comes back -- how do I do that? Thanks.

In case it's important. I am using Firebase as a back-end with Typescript

**udpate 1**

The api in question is for billing. As in `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher`. I am calling `.purchases.products.get`. And when I try to parse the response with `JSON.parse(apiResponse)`, I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at getItem (/srv/lib/index.js:31:69)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:145:8)
```

documentation: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get

**update 2**

Here is the apiResponse that I need to parse into json. I tried using `JSON.parse(apiResponse)` but got an error:

```
{ config: 
   { url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/mypath',
     method: 'GET',
     paramsSerializer: [Function],
     headers: 
      { 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
        'User-Agent': 'google-api-nodejs-client/2.0.0 (gzip)',
        Authorization: 'Bearer somecode',
        Accept: 'application/json' },
     params: {},
     validateStatus: [Function],
     retry: true,
     responseType: 'json' },
  data: 
   { kind: 'androidpublisher#productPurchase',
     purchaseTimeMillis: '111222333',
     purchaseState: 0,
     consumptionState: 1,
     developerPayload: '',
     orderId: 'some string',
     purchaseType: 0 },
  headers: 
   { 'alt-svc': 'quic=":111"; ma=33445566; v="a string"',
     'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform',
     connection: 'close',
     'content-encoding': 'gzip',
     'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
     date: 'Fri, 14 Jun 2019 12:40:12 GMT',
     etag: '"some string"',
     expires: 'Fri, 14 Jun 2019 12:40:12 GMT',
     server: 'GSE',
     'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
     vary: 'Origin, X-Origin',
     'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
     'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
     'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block' },
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK' }
```

The error is still the same as in "update 1"

Comment: You should consult the API documentation for the particular API you're calling (which you haven't mentioned yet here).  It should explain the structure of a response.

Comment: The response comes in the form of json. They don't have examples. Thanks!

Comment: The structure might be documented in a common way for all languages, not just JS.  If there is no documentation at all, that would make the API unusable, no?

Comment: Thanks! I have updated with details of which API I am using. https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get

Comment: There's a link on that page that sends you to the response object.

Comment: I have pasted the response I am getting as update 2. So now it's back to being about how to convert from apiResponse to JSON. I think the complaint has to do with the single quotes as opposed to the typical double quotes that json expect. But I am having a hard time fixing it. Using .replace(/'/g,'"') didn't help with the conversion to JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template strings will call `toString` on the parts. You need to do

```
console.log('You need to pass it as a parameter', apiResponse)
```

If you want to print the actual object to the console.

Comment: Awesome! I am now able to see the string version of the object doing exactly as you say. +1. But I am still not able to parse the `data` portion to json with `JSON.parse(apiResponse.data)`. I am updating the post to show the text version of the response. Thanks!

Comment: oh, I don't have enough reputation to upvote yet. :(

Comment: I was able to figure out the rest from there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The object has already been parsed. The error is from passing json to JSON.parse() which expects a string.

[object Object] is returned from the objects toString() method in a template literal, to avoid this: 
console.log('Some string',apiResponse);

if theres still a problem try console.log(JSON.stringify(apiResponse))